# pg_dump - Dump schema with special characters in the name

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, pg-dump

We are trying to make a backup file per database schema on our multi-tenant application.

We get the schema names list executing something like:

```sh
$ psql -d PG_DATABASE -t -c "select schema_name from information_schema.schemata;" | grep 'tenant_'
```

And then when execute a backup of each schema:

```sh
$ pg_dump -d PG_DATABASE --format=plain -n SCHEMA_NAME -f output.sql
```

But we are having issues with UTF-8 schema names like `tenant_eléctrico`:

```sh
$ pg_dump -d PG_DATABASE --format=plain -n "tenant_eléctrico" -f output.sql
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe3 0xa9 0x63
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT oid FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
WHERE n.nspname OPERATOR(pg_catalog.~) '^(tenant_el�ctrico)$'
```

We already tried with and without quoting (single and double quotes), trying to escape the special character as hexadecimal... without any good result.

How can I call `pg_dump` with a schema name that includes UTF-8 valid characters?
I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.15 at the moment.

We might remove those special characters in a near future, but if there is a way to do these backups in the meanwhile it would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like we found the answer!

We were running this inside a bash script or in the console itself, and the quotes were being interpreted by the shell, and not passed directly to `pg_dump`, as it expects for special characters.

The solution was escaping the quotes themselves:

```
$ pg_dump -d PG_DATABASE --format=plain -n \'tenant_eléctrico\' -f output.sql
```

or:

```
$ pg_dump -d PG_DATABASE --format=plain -n '"tenant_eléctrico"' -f output.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is inexplicable.

The UTF-8 encoding for `é` is `C3 A9`, and I cannot imagine anything that would turn it into `E3 A9`. It would be interesting to know your locale.

Anyway, a workaround would be to use a wildcard:

```sh
pg_dump -d PG_DATABASE --format=plain -n 'tenant_el*ctrico' -f output.sql
```